# Why can OuterClass.this not be accessed when invoking constructors?

Tags: java

There is something I stumbled upon when coding an explanational GUI for an algorithm.

I fully understand why the following doesn't work:

```
public class Superclass {
    public Superclass (int someValue) {
        // do something
    }
}

// new file

private class Subclass extends Superclass {
    int someValue; 
    public Subclass () {
        super (this.someValue);
        this.someValue = 0;
    }
}
```

The subclass is not yet fully initialized, so it makes no sense to use `this`.

I also understand why this doesn't work:

```
public class Superclass {

    public Superclass (int someValue) {
        // do something
    }

}

// new file

public class OuterClass {

    private class InnerSubclass extends Superclass {
        int someValue;
        public InnerSubclass () {
            super (this.someValue);
            this.someValue = 0;
        }

    }
    // some code of OuterClass
}
```

The situation doesn't change by the sole fact that the subclass is an inner class.

What I don't understand is why this doesn't work:

```
public class Superclass {

    public Superclass (int someValue) {
        // do something
    }

}

// new file

public class OuterClass {

    int someValue;

    private class InnerSubclass extends Superclass {
        public InnerSubclass () {
            super (OuterClass.this.someValue);
        }
    }

    public OuterClass () {
        this.someValue = 0;
    }
    // some code of OuterClass
}
```

Note that I use `OuterClass.this`, not the `this` of `InnerSubclass`. An outer class object needs to be initialized in order for an inner class object to even be creatible. The only case I can think of where this is not true is if the inner class is static, in which case `OuterClass.this` cannot be referenced at all.

Any idea why the code above still produces a `VerifyError`?

Comment: What Java compiler? Can you post the exact decompiled signature of the constructor?

Comment: How are you creating the instance of inner class?

Comment: Where do you get the error/stacktrace message? This works for me without any issues `OuterClass.InnerSubclass innerSubclass = outerClass.new InnerSubclass();`